# How to show sonarqube metrics reports in jenkins against each build

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I already implemented mashup portlets using dashboard view. However it can show last build report only.
I need to show report for all builds separately.
I also considered quality gates using sonar scanner but it wont serve the purpose here as I need report/metrics per build

Request for help from CI experts. Thanks in advance